# How to determine the angle between the segments being the circle radius?

Tags: python, geometry

I have this situation:

[image]

Where the points lying on the circle are the form:

```
(x1, y1) = [[-3.4999240122033539], [0.023063148145395788]]
(x2, y2) = [[-2.9590339872753137], [-1.86925596485595262]]
```

How to determine the angle at such coordinates of points?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about basic mathematics and not about programming.

Comment: no, not necessarily, because all the solutions I have found relate to points with integer coordinates, and there are some solutions to this, but I have a problem with real coordinates.

Comment: How do the integer coordinates solutions differ with the ones for real coordinates?

Comment: there was a problem in existing solutions with real coordinate processing.

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski Your motivation for asking this question may well be a programming problem, but the question the way you asked is not. If you have a problem with a particular implementation (i.e. coordinate processing) you should definitely mention that in the question ;)

Comment: OK I understand :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this

```
import numpy as np

def angle_between(p1, p2):
    ang1 = np.arctan2(*p1[::-1])
    ang2 = np.arctan2(*p2[::-1])
    return np.rad2deg((ang1 - ang2) % (2 * np.pi))
```

Read more about [arctan2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html)

Comment: This solution seems to assume that the circle is centered at the origin? (which is the case in the example) Maybe it should be expanded to the general case?

Answer (score 1):

This has a both a geometry/trigonometry part and a maths API part.

The basic idea is you calculate an angle from its `tan`, i.e. you use some `atan` or `arctan` function. To get an angle within the full four quadrant range, there usually is an `atan2` function which takes two parameters: the deltay and the deltax (which in this case, starting from (0,0), would be yn and xn).

In your case the conceptually simple way is to determine the difference of the `atan2` values of the two points.

In case you need to save one `atan2` call in favour of a few more multiplications and maybe the odd square root, you can determine the `tan` of your result using basically Pythagoras, and then fiddle with the signs a bit.